# Question about the proof of Riesz Representation theorem on applying monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem for $L^p$ spaces from Rene Schilling's Measure, Integrals, and Martingales and there is a single point that I'm not clear about.

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $1\le p <\infty$, $1<q\le \infty$ be conjugate indices. Let $I:L^p(\mu)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive linear functional.

Then $\nu:\mathscr{A}\to [0,\infty)$ defined by $\nu(A)=I(1_A)$ is a measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, and by the Radon-Nikodym theorem there is a positive measurable function $f\in \mathscr{M}(\mathscr{A})$ such that $$I(1_A)=\nu(A)=\int 1_A fd\mu \; \forall A\in \mathscr{A}.$$

By linearity, dominated convergence and the continuity of $I$ we have $$I(u)=\int ufd\mu \; \forall u \in L^p(\mu).$$

Now assume that $1<p<\infty$. Define $B_n:=\{f^{q-1}\le n\}\in \mathscr{A}.$ The function $u_n:= f^{q-1}1_{B_n}$ is bounded and with $u=u_n$ in the above equation we have
$$\int f^q 1_{B_n}d\mu=\int u_n f d\mu = I(u_n)\le \Vert I\Vert \cdot (\int f^q 1_{B_n}d\mu)^{1/p}.$$

The text says that we get with monotone convergence

$$\Vert f \Vert_q = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert f 1_{B_n} \Vert_q \le \Vert I\Vert.$$

My question is how does monotone convergence exactly apply here? Shouldn't we have $\sup_n f1_{B_n} = f 1_{\{f<\infty\}}$? Is this because $\nu(X)$ must be finite as well, so $\mu(f=\infty)=0$, and hence the $L^q$ norm for $f$ and $f1_{\{f<\infty\}}$ are the same?

Comment: Radon-Nikodym gives that $f\in L^1(\mu)$, so we must have $\mu(f=\infty)=0$.